# Рекурсия, запускаемая в цикле

Tags: рекурсия, циклы, javascript

Вот ссылка http://jsfiddle.net/92F94/
Вот код:

```
function lol(iter, depth){
    alert("Из итерации "+iter+", Глубина "+depth)
    if(depth<5){
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            lol(i,depth+1);
        }
    }
}
lol(0,0);
```

Я ожидаю, что в первом вызове функции она три раза вызовется в цикле, потом в каждый из этих вывозов ещё три раза, и ещё и ещё, итого у меня получится 3^5 вызовов. На деле же получилось, что она отрабатывает только 7 раз (Считаю без первого вызова). Почему так? Это я что-то делаю не так, или это баг/фича языка?

Comment: >Это я что-то делаю не так, или это баг/фича языка?

не глядя в код готов поставить миллион долларов, что это ваш баг, а не языка

Comment: @DreamChild
А поглядите, пожалуйста? Я совсем запутался._.

Comment: @DreamChild А, всё, не надо, разобрался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам.
Товарищи, не повторяйте моих ошибок, не забывайте var!

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
```